# How to Compare a string to each item in a file?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, comparison, .net

More or less, I need to compare a set string to every item in a file. I've already created the method for the comparison, however calling it is giving me trouble. The method is set up like this:

```
public static double CompareStrings(string str1, string str2){ //code here }
```

I know that `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines` will convert each line into a string and put it into an array. So can I compare each of those with a predefined string? Note: I am not looking if the file just contains the string.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: "So can I compare each of those with a predefined string?" --- yes you can! Where is my cookie?

Comment: @zerkms can you tell me how to do it? :P

Comment: "compare strings" is not sufficient requirements explanation. There are hundreds ways of comparing strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oo

array -> AllLines

mystring -> your predefined string

```
for (int i = 0; array[i]; i++){

CompareStrings(mystring, array[i]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should start by redefining the method signature:

```
public static int CompareStrings(string[] originalSet, params string[] compareToSet)
```

Then do the calculation stuff:

```
public static int CompareStrings(string[] originalSet, params string[] compareToSet)
{
    int hits = 0;
    foreach (string s in originalSet)
    {
        if (compareToSet.Contains(s))
        {
            hits++;
        }
    }

    return hits;
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
int hits = CompareStrings( File.ReadAllLines(filename)
                         , "match1"
                         , "match2"
                         );
```

Or like this:

```
int hits = CompareStrings( File.ReadAllLines(filename)
                         , File.ReadAllLines(filenameOfFileWithMatchList)
                         );
```

Or like this:

```
List<string> matchList = new List<string>();
matchList.Add("match1");
matchList.Add("match2");

int hits = CompareStrings( File.ReadAllLines(filename)
                         , matchList.ToArray()
                         );
```

Comment: In this case `double` return type looks like a total overkill and is just confusing

Comment: @zerkms: Me too, but it was in the original question. Will revert to `int`.